# Calculate time difference and display minutes only - Series Error

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the time difference of two time stamps in a pandas dataframe row. I tried the following:

```
t_end = pd.to_datetime(df["Offblock Dt M"])
t_begin = pd.to_datetime(df["Last_leg_onblock"])
gt_diff = pd.Timedelta(t_end - t_begin ).seconds / 3600.0 
df["GT_actual"] = np.where(is_first_leg, 0, gt_diff)
```

but I got a value error saying:

> ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta
> or convertible, not Series

The problem is with line 3 timedelta.
Any ideas how I can solve the issue?

Comment: The error itself is self explained. You are passing series data, instead try passing a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:-

```
gt_diff = pd.Timedelta(t_end - t_begin ).seconds / 3600.0
```

Use This:-

```
gt_diff=(t_end - t_begin).dt.total_seconds()/3600
```